# MySQL, confused about nested count

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is the table:

```
+------+--------+------+--------+
| sID  | sName  | GPA  | sizeHS |
+------+--------+------+--------+
|  123 | Amy    |  3.9 |   1000 |
|  234 | Bob    |  3.6 |   1500 |
|  345 | Craig  |  3.5 |    500 |
|  456 | Doris  |  3.9 |   1000 |
|  567 | Edward |  2.9 |   2000 |
|  678 | Fay    |  3.8 |    200 |
|  789 | Gary   |  3.4 |    800 |
|  987 | Helen  |  3.7 |    800 |
|  876 | Irene  |  3.9 |    400 |
|  765 | Jay    |  2.9 |   1500 |
|  654 | Amy    |  3.9 |   1000 |
|  543 | Craig  |  3.4 |   2000 |
+------+--------+------+--------+
```

I can't figure out what the logic is behind this query

```
select *
from Student S1
where (select count(*) from Student S2
   where S2.sID <> S1.sID and S2.GPA = S1.GPA) =
  (select count(*) from Student S2
   where S2.sID <> S1.sID and S2.sizeHS = S1.sizeHS);
```

This is what is returned:

```
+------+--------+------+--------+
| sID  | sName  | GPA  | sizeHS |
+------+--------+------+--------+
|  345 | Craig  |  3.5 |    500 |
|  567 | Edward |  2.9 |   2000 |
|  678 | Fay    |  3.8 |    200 |
|  789 | Gary   |  3.4 |    800 |
|  765 | Jay    |  2.9 |   1500 |
|  543 | Craig  |  3.4 |   2000 |
+------+--------+------+--------+
```

How is count, an aggregation command, able to equal another aggregation and return a table when it is a where criteria?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `count(*)` queries are being run as co-related sub-queries and they both return a single scalar value (an `integer`). 
Your main query does not have any aggregation of it's own.

The two `count(*)` queries return two numbers, which are being compared to each other in the `where` condition which is perfectly legal.

The query would evaluate to something like this:

```
select *
from Student S1
where (<count of students with the same GPA as this student>) 
        =
      (<count of students with the same sizeHS as this student>);
```

And then, for example, if the counts for a student (one record in the table) come back as `5` and `6`, then the `where` condition for that record will be evaluated as:

```
select *
from Student S1
where 5 
        =
      6;
```

Comment: Great explanation